# How to add a property to a div when an image is dropped inside it?

Tags: javascript, html, properties

I want to be able to add a property to a div when an image is dropped inside it, and the property taken away when the image is dragged outside the box. The property is going to be `ondrop="swapDrop(event)"`. I don't want to use jquery, just pure javascript. Also, I don't know if it is possible to not refer to an id, but if you have to, the ids for the divs are going to be:

```
div10 div11  div12 div13 div14 div15 div16 div17
```

I would appreciate any responses I get. 
Please ignore `div1 div2 div3 div4 div5 div6 div7 div8`

Directly edit the code: https://jsfiddle.net/wyq5oke1/2/

Comment: can you replicate it on plunker/fiddle.

Comment: @RiteshKashyap i did. now, can you take away my downvote?